# nagios core on centos (nginx) starts correctly but cant read any hosts or services

Tags: nginx, centos6, nagios

guys i have looked and searched and read. yum update changed a permission somewhere but cant find where. Nagios on centos starts correctly i can view the page but for some reason i dont see any hosts or services, only 403 forbidden in the corner.
ive checked my  nagios.cfg and no errors or warnings. I have started Nagios as daemon, same. Any other suggestions ?

```
total 160
drwxrwxr-x   5 root root    4096 May  7 18:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 78 root root    4096 May  8 22:38 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   11339 Sep 23  2014 cgi.cfg
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   11658 Aug 30  2013 cgi.cfg.rpmnew
drwxr-x---   5 root nagios  4096 Aug 30  2013 conf.d
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   43443 Oct  2  2014 nagios.cfg
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   44533 Aug 30  2013 nagios.cfg.rpmnew
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     960 Jul 24  2016 nrpe.cfg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     899 Mar 31  2015 nrpe.cfg.rpmsave
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    5332 Feb 24  2015 nsca.cfg
drwxr-x---   2 root nagios  4096 May  7 17:39 objects
-rw-r-----   1 root apache    27 Aug 30  2013 passwd
drwxr-x---   2 root nagios  4096 May  7 18:14 private
-rw-r-----   1 root root    1340 Aug 30  2013 resource.cfg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    1628 Mar 20  2013 send_nsca.cfg
```

the check configuration :

```
    Nagios Core 3.5.1
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 08-30-2013
License: GPL

Website: http://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
Processing object config directory '/etc/nagios/conf.d'...
Processing object config directory '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/jira-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/routers-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/ups-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/backup-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/clone-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/perforce-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/linux-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/servicegroups/web-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hostgroups.cfg'...
Processing object config directory '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/test.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/diskstation.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/clone-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/wifi.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/cloud.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/perforce-servers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/printers.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/hosts/switches.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/contacts.cfg'...
Processing object config directory '/etc/nagios/conf.d/commands'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/commands/notifications.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/commands/perfdata.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/commands/checks.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/commands/nrpe.cfg'...
Processing object config file '/etc/nagios/conf.d/templates.cfg'...
   Read object config files okay...

Running pre-flight check on configuration data...

Checking services...
        Checked 124 services.
Checking hosts...
        Checked 23 hosts.
Checking host groups...
        Checked 8 host groups.
Checking service groups...
        Checked 8 service groups.
Checking contacts...
        Checked 1 contacts.
Checking contact groups...
        Checked 1 contact groups.
Checking service escalations...
        Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking service dependencies...
        Checked 0 service dependencies.
Checking host escalations...
        Checked 0 host escalations.
Checking host dependencies...
        Checked 0 host dependencies.
Checking commands...
        Checked 27 commands.
Checking time periods...
        Checked 1 time periods.
Checking for circular paths between hosts...
Checking for circular host and service dependencies...
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   0

Things look okay - No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check
```

finally what i see :

[what is see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK54v.png)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your permissions are all messed up!

When you installed it.. was it from source? If so, did you use the `--with-nagios-user=` flag during `./configure`?

On one of my boxes I have a combination of apache and nagios as the `/usr/local/nagios` owners. Try this:

```
chown -R nagios:nagios /usr/local/nagios
chown -R apache:nagios /usr/local/nagios/etc
chmod +x -R /usr/local/nagios/bin /usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

You'll also want to make sure that the nagios user and group is set in the main configuration file (`/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg`), like this:

```
nagios_user=nagios
nagios_group=nagios
```

Also, did you remember to set up your htpasswd file?

```
htpasswd -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

Anyway, hope this helps get you started!

Comment: still nothing. everything seems fine with what you suggested to check. ill keep digging thanks for your help.